# virtualenvwrapper -> updating python binary

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm using virutalenvwrapper and created a virtualenv for my django application. I was running python 2.6.1. At the time i set this up
Unfortunately python 2.6.1 has a bug with respect to passing unicode strings in kwargs. As a result I'm looking to update the python binary used by my vritualenv.

Python 2.7.2 is all installed. I just need to understand what is the best way to "migrate" my current virtualenv to use the new python binary.

As i understand it, virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper are sensitive to the python used during install. Do i then,

1) uninstall and reinstall virtualenv, virutalenvwrapper while making sure i'm using python 2.7? If i do this, will the old virtualenv just work, or do i need to recreate it?

or

2) can i just somehow update the binary used in my virtualenv ?

---

**update:**
I just ended up creating a new env from scratch.
I did not uninstall and reinstall virutalenv or virtualenvwrapper. still don't know if that will bite me later on down the line but so far seems ok.

Would still like to know definitively if changing python versions on virtualenv wrapper and virtualenv is ok.

Answer (score 3):

`virtualenvwrapper` has a [`cpvirtualenv`](http://www.doughellmann.com/docs/virtualenvwrapper/command_ref.html#cpvirtualenv) command. Have you tried executing that from the new Python?

If that doesn't work, you could just destroy the old virtualenv and create a new one for your project. It should be easy if you have been diligent about keeping track of your dependencies (either in `setup.py` or `requirements.txt`). If you haven't been diligent, you can use `pip freeze` to capture the libs that are currently installed.

Comment: So it sounds like virtualenvwrapper and virtualenv are insensitive to the python version used at install? I can recreate the whole thing but one of the requirements is Pillow and i need to do a manual pip --no-install on it and modify config files and blah blah so just lazy to do that again.

Comment: virtualenv is sensitive the last time I tested it, but I thought cpvirtualenv might be able to fix the brokenness as part of its tweak age of the new virtualenv. Just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

So for the benefit of others who may be reading this.
Ran into an issue all of a sudden today. Upon logging in via ssh i was presented with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader, check that virtualenv has been installed for VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/home/*******/opt/bin/python and that PATH is set properly.
```

WTF. it was working fine for like... i guess a month now. Turns out maybe i never closed my ssh session (i.e. virtualenvwrapper never had to restart).

Google wasn't much help. As it turns out, the problem was exactly what the error message said. Virtualenv was not installed for the python specified. (2.7) 
It was installed for the version i was using previously (2.6)
D'oh.

Since i wasn't really using 2.6 anymore, i simply renamed the directory containing my local  site packages from

```
~/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages
```

to

```
~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

(site-packages is appended to the path just to make clear what and why i renamed)

Similarly, I could have just as easily run easy_install or pip to install virtualenvwrapper to a new local directory using the python2.7 binary. (which theoretically should have created the appropriate site-packages folder)